# why am i getting this error 'reshape_and_normalize_image' is not defined'?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to reshape and normalize a content_image using vgg-19 model

```
content_image = scipy.misc.imread("girl.jpg")
content_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(content_image)
```

and I also get the same error when performing the same action on a style_image

```
style_image = scipy.misc.imread("santorini.jpg")
style_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(style_image)
```

Comment: Did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't import the function 'reshape_and_normalize_image'
also It would be more helpful if you showed us what type of error you got